# Eval fields, if blank display other field

Tags: asp.net, eval

How would I go about getting this to work, it seems that this outputs the second output statement. I am trying to see if ContactFirstName and ContactLastName have a value in them if they dont then I want it to display the company in the place of the name. Am I go about this the right way?

```
<%# (Eval("ContactFirstName") == "" & Eval("ContactLastName") == "") ? Eval("ContactCompany", "") : Eval("ContactCompany", "{0}") %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ToString() to convert into string

```
<%# (Eval("ContactFirstName").ToString() == "" && Eval("ContactLastName").ToString() == "") ? Eval("ContactCompany") : Eval("ContactFirstName").ToString()+Eval("ContactLastName").ToString() %>
```